# Series shown up in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Here is the series, by some concepts in quantum mechanics, it should be 1, however, I don't know how to prove it. Could someone show me the proof? Thanks.
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{4}{n^2\pi^2}(1-\cos\frac{n\pi}{2})^2
$$

Comment: have you spend at least one or two own thoughts regarding a solution to your question?

Comment: Where do you get stuck? What is your first step?

Comment: @tired I tried, but I notice the cosine term may not vanish which may (actually must) contribute to the series.

Comment: so what is $\cos(n \pi/2)$ for $n=0,1,2,3 \mod 4$?

Comment: I just do not know how to start.

Comment: @HamioJiang my last comment should really push you in the right direction: decompose your sum in 4 parts depending on the remainder of $n \mod 4$. Now see how you can simplify

Comment: @NilabroSaha I just think it should be 1. If it is not equal to one, it will indicate my quantum problem should involve one more term, this is what I want to check. : )

Comment: @NilabroSaha the sum equals one (don't forget to square the numerator) so the conjecture of OP is true. Please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be defined as

$$
S=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2}\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)\right)^2
$$

Decompose $S$ according to the remainder of $n$ modulo $4$.

Since $\cos(\pi n/2)=1$ for $n=0 \mod 4$ one part of the sum exactly cancels. Furthermore $\color{blue}{\cos(n\pi/2)=0}$ for $\color{blue}{n=1,3\mod 4}$ and $\cos(n\pi/2)=-1$ for $n=2\mod 4$ which means that we can equally write

$$
S=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(4k+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(4k+3)^2}}+\frac{2^2}{(4k+2)^2}\right)=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}}+\frac{2^2}{(4k+2)^2}\right)=\\\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}}+\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}\right)=\frac{8}{\pi^2}{\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}}
$$

or

> $$
> S=1
> $$

Since

$$
{\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2}-\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2k)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\pi^2}{6}={\frac{\pi^2}{8}}
$$

From a number theoretical view we can identify the sum as

$$
S=\frac{4}{\pi^2}L(\chi_1,2)=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(1-\chi_1(n))^2}{n^2}
$$

where $\chi_1(n)$ is the non-trivial Dirichlet character associcated with the map $Z/4Z\rightarrow \mathbb{S_1}$

Comment: It really expands my view point, say $\chi _1$. I will check some related contents. Thanks! : )